# Cómo ver la información de una API en PYTHON?

Tags: python, api, pandas, data

Estoy tratando de obtener la información de la API para poder decidir con qué columnas empezar a trabajar. Escribí esto por ahora pero me tira error:

```
#Data
url = "https://ftx.us/api"
data = requests.get(url)
df = pd.read_json(url)
```

## ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\angel\OneDrive\Escritorio\PROYECTO 3\streamlit_app.py", line 21, in <module>
    df = pd.read_json(url)
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 207, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 588, in read_json
    json_reader = JsonReader(
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 673, in __init__
    data = self._get_data_from_filepath(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 710, in _get_data_from_filepath
    self.handles = get_handle(
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 667, in get_handle
    ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 336, in _get_filepath_or_buffer
    with urlopen(req_info) as req:
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 236, in urlopen
    return urllib.request.urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: Una vez que haces `requests.get`, el resultado lo estás guardando en `data`, deberías revisar el contenido de `data`, haciendo un `print(data.text)`

Answer (score 0):

Falta importar las librerias,a modo de ejemplo:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://ftx.us/api"
data = requests.get(url)
content_json = data.json()
print(content_json)
```

Respuesta:
**{'success': True, 'result': True}**

Comment: No creo que el no importar librerías sea la causa del error del OP, si no un sintoma de haber subido un código incompleto. Además, el OP busca cargar el contenido usando Pandas.